# Guidelines for Using Snowflake SQL Queries Online OR Downloading / Installing Snowflake on Laptop

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run some SQL queries for Snowflake database. But having issue to find Snowflake setup to download and install on my laptop.

- Is there some online site that facilitates to run Snowflake SQL queries? (Similar to https://livesql.oracle.com/)

OR

- Is there some way for downloading / installing Snowflake on laptop

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake is a SAAS product therefore you need a client application to connect to Snowflake and run queries.

To answer to your questions:

- `online site` - you can simply use a browser to connect to your Snowflake account and run SQL queries
- for a locally installed client from Snowflake you can use [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql).

If you want to try Snowflake for free, sign up for a trial using this [link](https://signup.snowflake.com/) and you get a Snowflake account you can use for 30 days for free (including $400 worth of free usage).

Comment: Thanks, I am developer and just want to learn Snowflake free. I am reading Snowflake SQL Queries, and My purpose is to run SQL Queries just for learning purpose. ... Is there some website that allow me to run snowflake sql queries free?

Comment: I've updated my answer adding the link to a free trial if you want.